# php cURL windows tcp

Tags: php, curl, tcp

running Xampp with PHP 7 on windows im trying to write a simple get work function for getting the newest work from a monero mining pool. 
Im getting the following error:
`CURL ERROR: Protocol "tcp" not supported or disabled in libcurl`

is there a lib im missing or a different version of the cURL dll i need?

I'm also open to other ideas for connecting to the server

Comment: Please check your php.ini settings. There should be some config options for curl. Be aware of proxy server (depends on your lcoal network).
You also have to check your windows environment variables.

Comment: the only lines containing cURL are:
`extension=php_curl.dll
[curl]
curl.cainfo="C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
[openssl]
openssl.cafile="C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"`

Comment: here is the code <code><?PHP
$stratumProxy = "tcp://pool.supportxmr.com:5555";
// reinitialize curl resource
$ch = curl_init();// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $stratumProxy);
//return the as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// echo output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Request Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
echo $output;
        // close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?></code>

Answer (score 0):

Here you got a basic method i wrote some months ago for my last project

```
/**
 * getJsonFromUrl
 *
 * (returns undecoded json format)
 *
 * @param string $targetUrl
 * @return string
 */
protected function getJsonFromUrl($targetUrl){

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $targetUrl);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
 }
```

In your comment you provided a code snippet. You might add the option for **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER**.

Please also remember if you are using a proxy for this connection: add the following code with your actual proxy address:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'PROXY_ADRESS:PROXY_PORT');
```

Just replace **PROXY_ADRESS** with your actual proxy netword adress and **PROXY_PORT** with the actual port

Comment: sorry it took so long getting back to this. it appears to be the way PHP was compiled on the machine. I am changing the entire project but thank you for trying to help